# irc client with good logging/autoconnect/authorize upon connect capabilities

Tags: windows-xp, irc

I need an IRC client with good logging / autoconnect upon disconnect / authorize upon succesful connect capabilities. Simply, something that will sit in the background and record some channels so I can quickly reread them later.

Windows XP platform.

Is there something like that on the market ? I knew of one or two 'in the old days' (of ibm terminals :-), but nowadays, all I see are simple gui clients without even the basic features. I know of mIRC (with which I've had some problems with reconnecting after server drops). Anything better out there ?

Just to clarify ... I'm not interested in a general irc client ... for that I have mIRC, with which I'm reasonably happy ... I  just need something which is really good at the above mentioned three things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)** should fit the bill, it will automatically reconnect upon disconnect, automatically join channels you select, and it will log all channels in separate HTML files.

Install the **[Plugin Pack](http://plugins.guifications.org/trac/wiki/PluginPack)** and activate IRC Helper and IRC More from the plugin menu.

### Update

Read the instructions for [IRC Helper](http://plugins.guifications.org/trac/wiki/irchelper) and [IRC More](http://plugins.guifications.org/trac/wiki/irc-more) plugins.

*Pidgin is free open source software (FOSS), a portable version is available [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/pidgin_portable).*

Comment: I was thinking something more in terms of authorizing me on nickserv's on different servers, identifying me on channels on different servers and such ... it capable of that ? (i would be satisfied with something like "Perform" option of mirc capabilities. Nothing more than that.).

Comment: When I was an IRC bunny I wrote a whole bunch of automation scripts to do this for me. I found the mIRC client to be the best, and the scripting language was easy to work with.

Comment: @ldigas - "it capable of that?" but of course, just create an IRC account in Pidgin for each nickname, join your channels, then right click on the channels in the buddy list and check the options Auto-Join and Persistent. Logging has to be enabled via Tools > Preferences > Logging, via Tools > Plugins you can enable Join/Part Hiding to suppress such useless messages, If you unzipped the plugin pack into the Plugin folder you can also enable IRC More and IRC Helper for even more options ... just take the Pidgin portable for a test drive, it won't do any harm. :)

Comment: @Molly - my nicks are registered with servers. That means when I log on I have to identify them (/msg nickserv identify nick) and possibly retake them (... ghost ...)if they are taken from someone else. It is not the same as simply logging on, with a non taken nick. I'll try Pidgin, but I haven't seen those actions possible on a lot of modern IM clients.

Comment: @Randolph Potter - i guess. it is fair enough, but (no idea why) i constantly have trouble reconnecting when my server splits from the network. and i can't connect to some outside servers due to some local restrictions (newly introduced ... go figure).

Comment: @ldigas - For Ghost and Auto-Reconnect you'll need ti extract IRC Helper and IRC More from the plugin pack into the plugin folder and then activate them from the plugin menu. then go to the accounts menu and edit your accounts, you will now see an Advanced tab, it's all there :)

Comment: Found it. Works ok for now. Will see how it'll behave ... thanks Mol' !

Comment: you're more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

I have a ZNC IRC bouncer set up (http://znc.in) which I have configured to log all chat in addition to replaying the recent history (buffer) when I connect from a client. I just wrote a little more about Znc over at this answer: [Accessing freenode without ports](https://superuser.com/questions/120922/accessing-freenode-without-ports/120963#120963) but it will do what you want and run as a service (Linux-based but there's a Windows port if you look). It will maintain your connection, identify with services, and allow you to connect from an unlimited number of clients (Pidgin works fine, it's what I use) on any platforms simultaneously, as one nickname and in all the same channels.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I prefer ChatZilla (http://chatzilla.hacksrus.com). It does everything you ask for.

See http://chatzilla.hacksrus.com/faq/#autoperform for automatically authorizing with nickserv for example.

ChatZilla is written in JavaScript, and can be scripted in that same language

**EDIT:**
ChatZilla is built to be run from Firefox, but you can also run it standalone using XULRunner: http://chatzilla.rdmsoft.com/xulrunner/ Google will tell you how to make it all portable so you can run it from a USB drive, if you need that.