# Can't connect to IRC Freenode from Taiwan (Colloquy)

Tags: irc, freenode

I'm studying Mandarin in Taiwan for 6 weeks and do web dev on the side. For some reason I can't connect to Freenode IRC with my Colloquy app. What's going on and how can I connect?

I don't see any logs of any kind an no errors either...

UPDATE: I think the ports are blocked on my router (6667). Can anyone recommend an alternative port? I tried port 22 and the log reads:

```
Debian-5+deb8u2
Protocol mismatch.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, so posting this for posterity:

Used port 6665.

Thans to a tip from this post: [Accessing freenode without ports](https://superuser.com/questions/120922/accessing-freenode-without-ports)